# Erro de sintaxe ao fazer dois updates em um único comando

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando efetuar um update em mais de uma tabela na mesma query, Local roda normal, porém online dá erro de sintaxe no MySQL 5.1.72. O que pode ser feito para resolver?

```
$query = 
    "UPDATE isc_products SET prodcurrentinv = 12, prodretailprice = 25, prodprice = 26 WHERE prodcode = 121212121212 LIMIT 1;" . 
    "UPDATE isc_product_variation_combinations SET vcstock = 54 WHERE vcsku = 121212121212 LIMIT 1;";
    $query = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $query->execute();
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE isc_product_variation_combinations SET vcstock = 54 WHERE vcsku = 1212121' at line 1' in /home/aoculist/public_html/admteste/template/main.php:5 Stack trace: #0 /home/aoculist/public_html/admteste/template/main.php(5): PDO->prepare('UPDATE isc_prod...') #1 /home/aoculist/public_html/admteste/index.php(55): include('/home/aoculist/...') #2 {main} thrown in /home/aoculist/public_html/admteste/template/main.php on line 5

Comment: Raphael, uma pergunta. Desenvolvendo Local vc ta em Windows e Servidor(online) Linux?

Comment: Windows, utilizando Zend Server. Online é Linux Zend Server também.

Comment: Posso estar falando asneira, pois não me lembro exatamente, mas creio já ter passado por isso, e o problema foi que a minha query estava com tabelas em minúsculo e no servidor estava em maiúsculo... o velho e simples problema de Case Sensitive, dá uma olhada como está a query e o banco online

Comment: Não, no servidor está tudo em minusculo, assim como foi escrito na query.

Comment: As versões de campos e tabelas do local está igual no servidor? ------ Acabei de ver uma coisa... no seu segundo Update dá um espaço depois do ; só pra matar minha curiosidade

Comment: Dá no mesmo problema.

Comment: Me surpreende que esteja rodando normal localmente. Tem certeza que está funcionando? Até onde eu sei, MySQL executado partir do PHP não permite dois comandos de uma vez só, assim, separados por ponto e vírgula.

Answer (score 1):

Por questões de segurança, por muito tempo não foi possível rodar mais de um comando SQL por vez, usando MySQL a partir do PHP.

Versões mais recentes do PDO aceitam múltiplos comandos.

> Para executar múltiplos comandos de uma vez você precisa:
>
> - PHP 5.3+
> - mysqlnd
> - Emulated prepared statements. Certifique-se que PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES está configurado para 1 (default).
>     Alternativamente você pode evitar usar *prepared statements* e usar
>     `$pdo->exec` diretamente.

Fonte da citação: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd